# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 5, number of columns: 4

Tags: java, postgresql

I am making a simple client banking application and I'm stuck here. I trying to update a row in the database I'm using eclipse, Dbeaver and PostqreSQL.

```
public Client updateClient (int clientId, AddUpdateDTO client) throws SQLException 
        
        try (Connection con = JDBCUtility.getConnection()){
            String sql = "UPDATE clients"
                    + "SET client_first_name = ?, "
                    + "client_last_name = ?, "
                    + "client_phone_number = ?, "
                    + "client_email"
                    + "WHERE"
                    + "client_id = ?; ";            
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            pst.setString(1, client.getFirstName());
            pst.setString(2, client.getLastName());
            pst.setString(3, client.getPhoneNumber());
            pst.setString(4, client.getEmail());
            pst.setInt(5, clientId);
            
            int updatedAmount = pst.executeUpdate();
            
            if (updatedAmount != 1) {
                throw new SQLException("Unable to find client record with Id of " +                          clientId);
            }
        }
        
        return new Client(clientId, client.getFirstName(), client.getLastName(), client.getPhoneNumber(), client.getEmail());       
    }
```

Here is my database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clients (client_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    client_first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    client_last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    client_phone_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    client_email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL  
);
```

All my other queries work such as add, delete, getAll, and etc I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: You have missprint in sql query. No "?" sign after client_email. This is cause of problem.

Comment: No *`= ?`* at the end of `client_email`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to assignment of the `client_email` field. Your query should look like that:

```
String sql = "UPDATE clients"
                    + "SET client_first_name = ?, "
                    + "client_last_name = ?, "
                    + "client_phone_number = ?, "
                    + "client_email = ?"
                    + "WHERE"
                    + "client_id = ?; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys that little mistake was killing me it works good now.